# Image in SVG file loses sharpness when zoomed in

Tags: c++, image, qt, svg, qwt

I am developing an application that uses the Qt and Qwt frameworks to plot graphs for a scientific project. The application needs to have functionality to save the charts in an SVG file in vector graphics format. Here is the code that saves the graph. (By the way, this code snippet is not from my original application, but a simple test program I wrote to simulate it.)

```
QSvgGenerator generator;
generator.setFileName(QString("sample").append(QString::number(rand() % 200)).append(QString(".svg")));
generator.setSize(ui.graphWidget->size());
generator.setViewBox(ui.graphWidget->rect());
generator.setTitle(QString("Sample graph"));

QPainter painter(&generator);
ui.graphWidget->render(&painter);
```

At first glance, the SVG image looked good and sharp. However, when I open it with Inkscape and zoom in by extremely large zoom ratios, the boundaries of the points in the scatter plot become blurry. 
Here is a screenshot:
[image: screenshot of graph after zooming in inkscape]

Notice that while the boundaries of the points have lost their sharpness, the graph annotations on the left side look as good as in the original image. To compare it with PNG format, which is strictly raster graphics, I tried saving the file in PNG format. When I opened the PNG file and zoomed in, I observed that it all broke down at a much lower zoom ratio. This shows that I am doing better than plain raster graphics. However, I need to figure out some way to make the graph look better when it is zoomed in. Here is the code snippet (again from the sample program) that plots the scatter graph.

```
plot = new QwtPlot(QwtText(QString("Sample plot")));
QPen pen(QColor(0, 0, 255));
pen.setWidth(3);
curve = new QwtPlotCurve();
curve->setStyle(QwtPlotCurve::Dots);

curve->setPen(pen);


QVector<QPointF> data;
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    data.append(QPointF((qreal)i, rand() % 10 + (rand() % 10) / 10.0 + (rand() % 10) / 100.0 + (rand() % 10) / 1000.0 + (rand() % 10) / 10000.0));
}

seriesData = new QwtPointSeriesData();
seriesData->setSamples(data);
curve->setData(seriesData);
    curve->attach(plot);

plot->setParent(ui.graphWidget);
plot->setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 800, 800));
plot->replot();
```

Can I fix this, or is it inevitable? Thank you for your attention and time.

Comment: I think it's something related to ***AntiAliasing*** from `QPaintEngine::PaintEngineFeatures` of `QSvgGenerator::paintEngine` and/or `QSvgGenerator::resolution`

Comment: can you post the source of the generated SVG XML?